# prevent IDM from downloading audio file in angular 6

Tags: angular6

I am playing an audio via code as

```
playAudio(file_name: string) {
   try {
      const srcFile: string = `./assets/audio/${file_name}`
      this.audio = new Audio(srcFile)
      this.audio.load()
      this.audio.play()
   } catch (err) {
      console.log(err.message)
   }
}
```

when I call this method, IDM gives file to download as in figure

[image]

What can be possible solution to prevent IDM or any other downloader from doing this

Comment: You might consider not using javascript as the playback mechanism but using and HTML5 `<audio>` element instead.
https://www.w3schools.com/Html/html5_audio.asp

Comment: can you give me a code sample to prevent IDM with `<audio>`